# Simple Question About - Firebase + Node.js/Express API + Cloud Firestone Rules /

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote API with node.js / express + Firebase/Functions, for DB using Cloud Firestone,
I see there is tab for rules to protect Database, I wrote rule but not any sence :(
I can even fetch date from Postman, jsbin e.t.c
so this rules can't help me to protect my DB? I can write some logic in node/express side but is another way to secure db or in this case i can only protect in server-side ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Security rules **only** control access from web and mobile clients using the Firebase SDKs.  Backend code using one of the the server SDKs completely bypass all security rules.  If you have constraints for accessing the database from a backend, you will have to code that logic separately - security rules will be of no use to you.

Security rules are intended to help you control access coming from frontend code, which is never really secure.  In many cases, you can use security rules instead of implementing your own backend to check access.  But if you prefer to build your own API, that's fine - just implement your access control in the backend instead of security rules.